# Как вернуть результат функции на Django в React Native приложение?

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Я изучаю бэкенд Django и я пишу React Native мобильное приложение, которое распознает текст с изображения с использованием Django. Как оно работает:
С мобильного приложения я отправляю изображение через POST-запрос, оно попадает на сервер, и далее там начинает срабатывать функция распознавания текста. Результат функции сохраняется внутри локального массива этой функции и выводится пока что в консоле Django. Но я пока не могу понять, как мне передать этот результат обратно на мобильное приложение.

Возможно мне нужно создавать еще один класс в модели Django, либо есть способ его внутри функции отправить на мобилку, если кто-то разбирается, то можете объяснить как это сделать:)

Django-Сервер:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Ocr(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Ocr

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ocr
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Ocr
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
# Create your views here.

from django.http.response import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.

# import pytesseract to convert text in image to string
import pytesseract
# import summarize to summarize the ocred text

from .forms import ImageUpload
import os

# import Image from PIL to read image
from PIL import Image

from django.conf import settings

# Create your views here.

class PostView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = Ocr.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if posts_serializer.is_valid():
            text = ""
            message = ""
            posts_serializer.save()
            try:
                posts_serializer.save()
                image = request.FILES['image']
                image = image.name
                path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
                pathz = path + "/images/" + image

                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(pathz), lang='rus+eng')

                os.remove(pathz)
            except Exception:
                message = "check your filename and ensure it doesn't have any space or check if it has any text"
            context = {
                    'text': text,
                    'message': message
            }
            print(context)
            return Response(posts_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(posts_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

React-Native:

CameraScreen.js:

```
const postToServer = (img) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('image', {
                uri: img.uri,
                type: 'image/jpeg', 
                name: 'test.jpg',
            })
    formData.append('title', 'title');
        
        fetch('http://192.168.0.149:8000/api/textocr/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          // If you add this, upload won't work
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За отправку с сервера в Django отвечает `return Response( )`

Для получения на клиенте вам надо правильно использовать `fetch` - либо два `await`, либо два `then`.

Это простейший пример, должен использоваться внутри асинхронной функции:

```
let response = await fetch(url);

let data = await response.json();
```

[Подробнее про fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

Если понимаете, что данные приходят не те или в неправильном формате, смотрите, что передаёте в `Response` в django.

[Про Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/)

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, я разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Вот, что я использовал со стороны React Native:

```
const postToServer = async (img) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('image', {
                uri: img.uri,
                type: 'image/jpeg', 
                name: 'test.jpg',
            })
    formData.append('title', 'title');
        
        let res = await fetch('http://192.168.0.149:8000/api/textocr/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        });
        let json = await res.json();
        console.log(json);
  }
```

Ну и соответственно, я отправляю картину на сервер, и с сервера он возвращается в в консоле react native:

```
Object {
  "result": "Но тут интервью вышло с министром
образования, он говорит что с лета
скорее всего будут рассматривать
заявления ene
",
}
```